Error Casteando un Objeto en Java Spring Boot
Tengo un problema al intentar hacer el casting en Spring Boot, tengo el siguiente método en el que hice el casting:
@Override
  public void modificarExpediente(AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand modificarComand) {

    **var comando = (EditarDevengadoComand) modificarComand;**
     //Más código
 

Este método es llamado dentro de todo un flujo, haciendo debug, en este punto el objeto 'modificarComand' es de tipo 'ModificarComand' la cual es una clase que extiende de la clase 'AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand'.
Adicionalmente, la clase 'EditarDevengadoCommand' es una clase que extiende de 'ModificarCommand' que a su vez extiende a 'AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand'.

Como indicación la clase 'ModificarCommand' y 'AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand' son clases que pertenecen a un módulo externo, es decir a una librería que se importa en el pom.xml.

Las clases serían como estas


//MÓDULO B
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@FieldDefaults(nivel = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperConstructor
public class ModificarCommand extends AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand {

    .....

}

//MÓDULO B
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@FieldDefaults(nivel = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@SuperConstructor
public abstract class AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand {

  ....
}

//Clase en Módulo A que extiende de una clase de un Módulo B

public class EditarDevengadoCommand extends ModificarCommand {

  ....
}


El error que obtengo es el siguiente ** //ERROR ACTUAL**

java.lang.ClassCastException: class ...ModuleB...ModificarCommand cannot be cast to class ...ModuleA....EditarDevengadoCommand (...ModuleB...ModificarCommand and ...ModuleA....EditarDevengadoCommand are in unnamed module of loader 'app')



Anteriormente tuve un error relacionado con Spring DevTools, que era algo asi :

java.lang.ClassCastException: class <Class_Name> cannot be cast to class <Class_Name> (<Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader <Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader 'app').



Pero desactivé spring dev tools de la siguiente manera y ya no sale error de Spring dev tools sino solo el primer error

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: false



Agradecería si alguien supiera como proceder en situaciones como éstas, gracias de antemano


Por lo que he leído por ahí parece que el problema está causado por el loader de las devtools. Dado que ya tienes el restart deshabilitado... simplemente quita las devtools del POM si no la estás usando. Si la estás usando aquí hay un comentario que recomienda añadir la librería externa a tu PATH del proyecto. Tal vez podrías echarle un ojo. El hecho de que el devtools estuviese tirándote un error similar me da la sensación de que el problema es efectivamente con él, y realmente tu config no desactiva el devtools como tal

Hola @Benito-B  Estoy usando gradle, probé quitando la dependencia spring dev tools pero igual sale el error de esta pregunta, vi tu enlace, agregué un archivo llamado "spring-dev-tools.properties"  en META-INF, en donde hice referencia al jar de donde viene las clases del otro modulo, el jar se llama "expediente-lib-0.3.1", entonces probé estas 2 formas:
restart.include.expediente-lib=/expediente-lib-..jar
restart.include.expediente-lib-0.3.1=/expediente-lib-0.3.1..jar
Aun asi me sigue saliendo el mismo error, debería poner una ruta mas especifica ? No encontre otra solución
